# SQL: How do I design a versioned key:value pair, allowing for non-unique values?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlite

I am looking for advice on how to implement a versioned key:val pair in any SQL flavor.

(Let's assume SQlite and Postgres for now.)

I have a table that is preliminarily like this:

```
locale key version -> value
```

The locale and key form the original unversioned candidate/primary key. The version is added to allow storing multiple versions.

The tricky part is that "updates" in the source data (that I do not control) may bump the version number without changing the value. In these cases I would like to suppress bumping the version number.

However, I cannot stipulate that the value is unique, because I wish to allow values to toggle, e.g.

```
en_US key1 1 -> "hello world"
en_US key1 42 -> "henlo world"
en_US key1 57 -> "hello world"
```

is a valid sequence: an error was accidentally introduced and then rolled back. Preserving the data as it existed circa version 42 is important.

However, we may often find that version 58 of the source data does not update the key's value - so this is a "last modified in" version semantic.

e.g. the following is an invalid sequence:

```
en_US key1 57 -> "hello world"
en_US key1 58 -> "hello world"
```

To preserve "last modified" semantics, the version 58 entry should not have been added.

I could do an "insert if" style check and query if the latest version for a locale/key matches the version received, but I worry this opens me up to race conditions.

Is there a more fundamental way to model this constraint in sqlite/postgres? I'm not sure what this kind of constraint is called formally. (It's not quite "unique".)

Comment: "I am worried about race conditions" - how so?

Comment: I'm curious about the application of all of this.  My first thought is an UPSERT, that is, an `INSERT` that will fail if the new row has the same content as the last one.  In Postgres you add an `ON CONFLICT UPDATE` clause that catches the failed `INSERT` and does an `UPDATE` instead.  How to make the `INSERT` fail without a unique constraint, I'm not sure.  Maybe a `CHECK` constraint.

Comment: Good question - source data is versioned but I need to compile a history such that past versions can be recalled/utilized. Not many keys out of a large set change between versions, hence the desire to keep a "changed in" version semantic. There's probably a more fundamental way to do this, but the versions themselves are useful to clients and cannot be internally arbitrary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constraint you mention is a business rule. It's an example of a perfectly logical requirement that cannot neatly be encoded in a relational schema. Your rule seems to be "for a given record identified by a key and locale, the system should reject inserts where the inserted value is the same as the latest value".

Most database constraints are designed to model the identity or relationships between tables, or the data types that an attribute may have.  Business rules *may* coincide with those concerns (e.g. "all phone numbers must be unique"), but that's not the primary purpose of the relational constraints.

So, I would implement this as you implement any other business rule, either by verifying in the application logic, in your SQL statement, or via a trigger on the table.

Comment: I second this, there is no way to implement this using plain SQL constraints. If you're using Postgres I'd go with a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger, returning `null` to make the insert silently fail if the value hasn't change since the last version

Comment: OK, makes sense. Application logic or triggers it is. I'm not always well versed in modern SQL implementation features and I'm always trying to centralize as much logic as possible. I will relent! (I suppose I just need to make sure my read-write is atomic.)